# How do I make sense of the solution to this circuit analysis problem?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, thermocouple

I am studying MIT's 6.01 on OCW and have been struggling with a sample final exam problem that involves circuit analysis with op amps. I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to approach the problem or at least how to get started, because while I have gotten pretty decent at solving basic op amp circuits through this course, I'm at a bit of a loss with this one. The problem and answer are included below, but I'm not sure how they got to the solution. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The last statement (stated badly, but reading between the lines) says that common-mode voltage can vary over a wide range, which means we need a differential amplifier. When delta-T is 1 degree, the equation at the top tells us that delta-V is 20 mV. Since they want an output of 5 V under these conditions, that means that the gain of the differential amplifier needs to be 250.

Comment: Thanks. I think that makes some sense, but just very different from the circuit problems I've typically seen in this course. This is probably a dumb question because I think the last sentence answers it, but this is not a situation where the op amp would be ideal (i.e. V+ = V-) right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In this problem we ARE assuming the opamp itself is ideal (infinite gain, infinite input impedance, zero output impedance, unlimited output current, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

(V- - V+) = k(Tr - Th). Problem data: When (Tr - Th) = 1F and K = 0.02, then:
(V- - V+) = 0.02x(1). Then (V- - V+) = 0.02 V. You should use a differential amplifier for converter the (V- - V+) difference in a Vo voltage. Then the differential amplifier gain should be G = Vo/(V- - V+). Calculating, G = 5/(0.02). Then G = 250. Using an operational amplifier to build a differential amplifier, we obtain:  Vo = R2/R1(V- - V+). As a gain is 250, R2/R1 = 250. If R1 = 1 kΩ is chosen, then we get R2 = 250 kΩ.